# As String vs As String() in VBA

Tags: string, vb.net

I'm new to VB.Net and would like to know what is the key difference between declaring a string as

```
Dim stringVariable As String
```

and

```
Dim otherStringVariable As String()
```

Thanks

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Concepts/Getting-Started/declaring-arrays

Comment: I do not think that is vba.  vba would be: `Dim otherStringVariable() As String` are you sure you are not using vb.net?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881859/mystring-or-as-string